# SailsJS MongoDB connector error: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager: MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am getting the error : error: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager: MongoError: Authentication failed. Password is fine and I am able to connect with MongoExpress from another server and Mongo Compass. I triple checked the password and even copy-pasted the connection URL to make sure it was not a typo error.

I have followed the instructions (https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-mongo-db) but the only difference is I added the password in the URL ('mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/mydb') as the Sails auto-migrate process was throwing a mongo-error like need Auth to drop.

Mongo db version v4.4.4

sails-mongo 1.2.0

Sails v1.4.2.

```
--datastore.js
default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/mydb',
}

--model.js
  attributes: {
    //MONGO
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
}

use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @ChrisMcClellan. Yes, I did but it has been a while and I don't remember the details. I usually post my solutions on sites like this but I didn't for this one as I didn't had any response and forgot about it. 

If you have a similar issue, I think my issue was related to the line id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' }. It is different for Mongo and even if I had follow the documentation it was still not working. After trials and errors with this line, it worked. PS. Sorry for the vague response, it has been months.

Comment: @Chris McClellan check if `mongod` service is running. If not then restart it `systemctl start mongod`